# How to query Kubernetes node CPU levels

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have the following PromQL query to get the CPU percentages of the nodes in my Kubernetes cluster.

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle|wait|iowait"}[5m])) * 100) > 80
```

I also have setup the alerts.

Problem I have here is, even though the alerts are triggering, when the CPU is > 80%, when I actually check the nodes with `kubectl top nodes` or from Azure Portal (as I have an AKS cluster), the nodes' CPU levels are nowhere near 80% (most of the times they are around 20%-30%)

Could someone please help me to adjust this query so I can get the average CPU of **each** node?

Comment: it might help of you provide the example output you want to achieve. should it be the same as `kubectl top nodes` per-node?

Comment: Hi @star67 i am looking for a percentage very much similar to what we see with `kubectl top nodes`